# Django UpdateView with some fields as just text

Tags: django

Ok, I have my CreateView working, and my UpdateView works, but I would like a couple of the fields to appear in my template as just text.  So I think I would not include them in the fields list, but need to add them into the context before rendering, but I can't figure out how to grab those values.

My Models:

```
class ProjectStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ProjectStatus)

class WorkLog(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    log_date = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)
    accomplishments = models.TextField()
```

My View:

```
class WorklogUpdate(UpdateView):

model = WorkLog
fields = [ 'project', 'log_date', 'accomplishments']
template_name_suffix = '_update_form'


def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = super(WorklogUpdate, self).get_form(form_class)
    form.fields['log_date'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'datepicker'})
    return form

@method_decorator(permission_required('worklogs.change_worklog'))
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(WorklogUpdate, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and my template:

```
{% extends "worklogs/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Edit Worklog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Project {{ form.project.value }}</h3> // Just need the project name
<h4>{{ form.log_date.value }}</h4>        // Just the worklog log_date value

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}   // essentially just the accomplishments field
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

In my form, I would like 'project' and 'log_date' sent to the template as just text and not appear as a field, leaving accomplishments as the editable part of the view.  I have my attempted fields as h3 & h4, and the log_date will display, but since the project is a dropdown, the most I can get is the option position.  I've been trying to grok get_form_kwargs to see if I could accomplish it there, but it isn't clicking.

I think 75% of what I've learned about Django has been from StackOverflow, so I am very grateful!

EDIT:  This is how I made it work, adding a get_context_data and the tidbit I was lacking was self.get.object.xxx

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(WorklogUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['project'] = self.get_object().project
    context['log_date'] = self.get_object().log_date
    return context
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update the [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.render) with additional information, more than just the form that you are returning.

Add the information to the context, and then on your page you will have `{{ log }}` and `{{ project }}` in the view.

Comment: OK, that makes sense and gets me closer, but the log and project are fields in the query, ie, record 28 is "Project X" as project, "1/23/89" as log_date, and then "blah" as accomplishments.  So accomplishments will be returned in the form, but how to I pull the project and log_date out of the query?

Comment: The datepicker widget is a leftover, I'm taking it out, also.

Comment: That will throw an error. `get form` must return `Form` instance, not `HttpResponse`

Comment: So I'm thinking I want to do it in get_context_data, I just don't see how I can pull the info from the object.

Comment: I removed the render_to_response stuff, i don't want to be spreading missinformation.

Comment: OK, so this is what I ended up doing, and it seems to work:

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(WorklogUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['project'] = self.get_object().project
    context['log_date'] = self.get_object().log_date
    return context
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't answer my own question until I wait 8 hours since I'm a newb.